# Which keccak algorithm does Monero use in its initial has function?

Tags: hash-verification, transaction-hash, proof-of-work-security, monero-hash

The Monero algorithm says

```
    First, the input is hashed using Keccak [KECCAK] with parameters b =
   1600 and c = 512
```

I'm trying to re-create teh algorithm using JS and I found this keccak library -- https://github.com/emn178/js-sha3 , but my question is which keccak algorithm is the documentation referring to -- keccak512, keccak384, keccak256?  Still struggling to figure out all this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monero uses keccak-256, where 256 refers to the bit length of the hash produced.

Note that SHA-3-256 is slightly different, and so will not produce the same result as keccak-256.

This library will produce the correct hash: https://www.npmjs.com/package/keccak

Comment: It is worth noting Monero is like Ethereum with respect to what flavor of Keccak is being used by Monero.